# Finding partial derivatives for $\log (1+z) + xy$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I have an equation $\log (1+z) + xy^2 = 1-z$ and need to find $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$. Also, it is given that $z$ is implicitly defined by $x$ and $y$. How do I do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$

$$ \frac{1}{1+z} \left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} \right) + y^2 = -\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} $$

$$ \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = -\frac{y^2(1+z)}{2+z} $$

Now for $\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$

$$ \frac{1}{1+z} \left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} \right) + 2xy = -\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} $$

$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} = -\frac{2xy(1+z)}{2+z} $$